# How to generate people(number) - normal probability distribution

Tags: java, gaussian

My job is to generate and urban residents using normal probability distribution.

Number of cities, 3000, Population 15 000 000

(in JAVA)

```
    int people = 15000000;
    int[] arrayofcity = new int[3000]
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayofcity.length; i++) {
            //how to generate people to the towns of total
            //nextGaussian()??

    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: **1:** What have you tried? **2:** Please explain this more thoroughly. **3:** Don't expect people to do your homework.

Comment: Are you asking "how to populate cities in normal distribution such that sum of all cities is 15M" ?

Comment: U want the sum of populations of all the 3000 cities to be equal to 15 000 000 ??

Comment: Troubleshoot: it isnt home work, it is project.

amit,X86 : Yes, it is true

Comment: Populations of cities are not normally distributed, rather they obey http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.. Not very efficient as the distributions are averaged/cancelled for every 2 values.

```
int people = 15000000;
    int[] arrayofcity = new int[3000];
    int sharedSpread=people/3000;                 // sharedSpread= avg population
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayofcity.length; i++) {

        if(i%2!=0)
          arrayOfCity[i] = sharedSpread + (sharedSpread-arrayOfCity[i-1]);
        else
            {
             Random r = new Random();
             int val = Random.nextInt();
             arrayOfCity[i] = val%sharedSpread ;   

            }

    }
```

PS: This is not the exact code, but this can show how to go about the problem.. You can change the frequency of distribution . Instead of 2 here, we can change it to 4 to get better random distributions...

Answer (score 0):

One (non efficient, but beautiful mathematically IMO) way to do it is:

> For each person (repeat 15M times), choose with uniform distribution
>   his city.

It will give you a total sum of 15M people in all cities, and according to [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) - you will get close to normal distributionin in each city, because each city is basically a sum of [Bernoulli trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) with `p=1/3000`, over 15M trials.

Answer (score 0):

A rough sketch of a method:

- Use Random#nextGaussian() to create a value X between 0-1 for each city.
- Calculate the sum of all these X values. Call it S.
- For each city, take its value X and divide by S. Multiply this result by the total population (15 000 000). This is how many people live in this city.

Note that this would be tricky to implement in practice due to rounding. As such, the total population may be slightly above/below the desired 15 000 000, so some method will be needed to add/remove the extra people.